# React Bootstrap: Align col so that the col on the right will be displayed on top of the col on the left

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm wondering if there's a way with React Bootstrap to display two columns next to each other, but whenever the screen gets smaller, display the column on the right on top of the col on the left instead of the other way around.

Here's my code:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Row>
        <Col sm={8}>
          <Card>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Left Card/Bottom Card</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col sm={4}>
          <Card>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Right Card/Top Card</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, here's a link to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-sunset-pws5l)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the order classes..

```
       <Container className="App" fluid={true}>
          <Row>
            <Col sm={8} className="order-last order-sm-first">
              <Card>
                ...
              </Card>
            </Col>
            <Col sm={4}>
              <Card>
                ...
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
       </Container>
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/1yq2pod9K5)